# Use Pandas to merge two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrames below:

```
DataFrame1
   id  a comment
0   1  1     yes
1   2  2      no
2   3  3     yes
```

```
DataFrame2
   id  a
0   2  5
1   4  4
```

I'd like to update `DataFrame1` with the contents of `DataFrame2` based on the `id` column. Any new rows found in `DataFrame2` not in `DataFrame1` should be appended.
The result should look like this:

```
DataFrame3
   id  a comment
0   1  1     yes
1   2  5      no
2   3  3     yes
3   4  4
```

I've tried using a mixture of DataFrame update/append/concat functions but can't quite get what I'm looking for.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a left join, then when everything is aligned, update one column form the other column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `concat` then `groupby`:

```
pd.concat([df2,df1]).groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
   id  a comment
0   1  1     yes
1   2  5      no
2   3  3     yes
3   4  4     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

panda is a data display function, in python if the original data is in a dictionary you can mydict.update('key' : 'value') or mydict['key'] = value will also work.
I think panda has a reverse function to get back the original dictionary.  but I doubt that once it is in panda form that it can be manipulated as such.  someone will let you know if this is wrong.  I only use the panda data to display stuff because it is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas.DataFrame.merge should do it you can do database joins an update should work.