# Replace a row in a pandas DataFrame with a dict item based on a unique column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assume that you have a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[100,1000111,1.25,10,1,-1],
    [200,1000115,2.2,20,2,-2],
    [300,1000311,3.2,30,3,-3],
    [400,1000351,8.7,90,7,-1]],
    columns=['a','unique','c','d','e','f'])
```

Which looks like this:

```
     a   unique     c   d  e  f
 0  100  1000111  1.25  10  1 -1
 1  200  1000115  2.20  20  2 -2
 2  300  1000311  3.20  30  3 -3
 3  400  1000351  8.70  90  7 -1
```

Now you have a dictionary like this:

```
my_dtnry = {'a':50, 'unique':1000115, 'c':700, 'd':1, 'e':-10, 'f':3}
```

We focus on the **unique** column and seek the unique value from the dictionary. In this example the unique value is 1000115 and exists in the second row (ie. row 1).

So the question is, how can one easily [1] **find the correct row** and then [2] **replace all the values** of row 1 with the dict values ?

So the desired output would be:

```
     a   unique     c    d   e  f
  0  100  1000111  1.25  10  1 -1
  1  50   1000115  700   1  -10 3   # <- this row replaced with the dict
  2  300  1000311  3.20  30  3 -3
  3  400  1000351  8.70  90  7 -1
```

In particular, is there a specific (known standard pythonic) method that would do this efficiently as opposed to iterating the rows and columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
df.loc[df['unique']==my_dtnry['unique']] = [pd.Series(my_dtnry)]
```

Comment: looks like this works. I will wait for other answers (before accepting), but this looks like it might be the most pythonic way.

Comment: further question:  what if one wanted to do the same, but this time replacing with all items from a second 'smaller' dataframe that had a **unique** column ?

Comment: Set `unique` as index and use [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)? Also, see [concat and groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65258251/use-pandas-to-merge-two-dataframes/65258265#65258265).